# Why local storage vairable not being assigned to storage variable?

Tags: solidity

from solidity documentation

```
Assignments from storage to a local storage variable also only assign a reference.
```

In this contract, when I  am  intialising x in the function, it defaults to a data location in storage,
so it must reference the data.

why deleting x is not deleting the data?

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.0;

contract DeleteExample {
    uint data;
    uint[] dataArray;

    function f() public {
        uint x = data;
        delete x; // sets x to 0, does not affect data
        delete data; // sets data to 0, does not affect x
        uint[] storage y = dataArray;
        delete dataArray; // this sets dataArray.length to zero, but as uint[] is a complex object, also
        // y is affected which is an alias to the storage object
        // On the other hand: "delete y" is not valid, as assignments to local variables
        // referencing storage objects can only be made from existing storage objects.
        assert(y.length == 0);
    }
}
```

but when we initialized y with storage, it clearly referenced to the original dataarray.
I was under the impression that local variables will always be stored on in-memory until storage is defined explicitly. am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really not clear what you are asking.

> when I am intialising x in the function, it defaults to a data location in storage

No. `x` is a memory variable. The scaler types default to memory, so `x` is not a storage variable. It is a bad idea to instantiate any storage variables (not pointers) inside functions even if the compiler seems to let you.

> why deleting x is not deleting the data?

What data? I don't see `x =` in this function, so `x` refers to an unset uint, so `0`.

> I was under the impression that local variables will always be stored on in-memory until storage is defined explicitly. am I wrong?

Yes, for scaler types. For indexed types (structs, mappings, arrays) you must explicitly indicate `memory` or `storage`.

> why deleting x is not deleting the data?

It doesn't seem like `x` or `data` was set to anything and it doesn't seem like you tested anything after `delete x`. It's unclear how you reached any conclusion or what you are attempting to prove.

This might possibly clear up some things.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.0 <0.7.0;

contract DeleteExample {
    uint data = 10;
    uint[] array;

    function f() public {
        uint x = data;                              // to memory from storage
        delete data;                                // delete from storage
        require(x == 10, "it was affected.");
        x = data;                                   // update memory from storage
        require(x == 0, "it was not deleted.");
    }

    function g() public {
        uint[] storage mem = array;                 // storage pointer
        array.push(1);
        array.push(11);
        array.push(21);
        require(mem.length == 3, "not three elements.");
        require(mem[0]==1, "not one.");
        require(mem[1]==11, "not eleven.");
        require(mem[2]==21, "not twenty-one.");
        delete array[1];                            // delete from storage
        require(mem[1]==0, "element not gone.");    // storage pointer affected
    }
}
```

This blog might help: [Storage Pointers in Solidity](https://blog.b9lab.com/storage-pointers-in-solidity-7dcfaa536089).

Hope it helps.